# How can I create sections on my app?

Tags: java, android

I want to improve my new app so I have question for you. How can I make sections in my app, in Navigation Drawer?

[There's a photo if you don't understand what's in my mind. This photo is from Google Play](https://i.stack.imgur.com/65r7O.png)

There's my activity_main_drawer.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_pagrindinis"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_pagrindinis"
        android:title="Pagrindinis" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_soctinklai"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_soctinklai"
        android:title="Gimnazijos socialiniai tinklai" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_dienynas"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_dienynas"
        android:title="El. dienynas" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_naudingosnuor"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_naudingosnuor"
        android:title="Naudingos nuorodos"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_kontaktai"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_kontaktai"
        android:title="Kontaktinė informacija" />
</group>
```

And there's an excerpt from MainActivity.java

```
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_pagrindinis) {
        //Set the fragment initially
        PagrindinisFragment fragment = new PagrindinisFragment();
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
        // Handle the camera action
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_soctinklai) {
        //Set the fragment initially
        SocTinklaiFragment fragment = new SocTinklaiFragment();
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_dienynas) {

        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        i.setData(Uri.parse("https://sistema.tamo.lt"));
        startActivity(i);

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_naudingosnuor) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_kontaktai) {

        KontaktaiFragment fragment = new KontaktaiFragment();
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

I want to make section in this place. And if I press on it, it opens more sections in Navigation Drawer.

```
android:id="@+id/nav_naudingosnuor"
```

Comment: This is a really broad question. You should try narrowing it down.

Comment: For example if I press on the android:id="@+id/nav_naudingosnuor" it opens more sections something like in the photo.

Comment: What we mean is, narrow down the question to the specific step in the process that you are having trouble with. Right now the question is very broad - How do I add this whole new set of functionality to my app?

Answer (score 0):

There are available libs try one like that: https://github.com/PrashamTrivedi/DrawerLayoutTest

otherwise you need to create your own expandable list view.